# Writing IF THEN statements in WHERE Clause of SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am working in Access to write a search form for my database.  I want to have a form with 5 fields to search by.  IF there something in the field, it needs to search within those parameters - Else the field needs to be ignored.  here is what I am working with now, but I am having trouble getting it to work.  The types of fields to search by will be 1. Combo Box 2. Date Ranges

```
Select *
From NLog
Where
If [Forms]![Search]![Textbox1] > 0 THEN [Forms]![Search]![Textbox1] = Nlog.CoNo
Else Conintue
```

Thank you!

Comment: `case` `then` is SQL is the equivalent of `if` `then`.

Comment: Assuming access is similar enough to the rest of sql, you would use a `CASE` statement with something like this:  `WHERE Nlog.CoNo = CASE WHEN [Forms]![Search]![Textbox1] > 0 THEN [Forms]![Search]![Textbox1] ELSE NULL END` Of course, there's no reason you couldn't just use regular boolean logic: `WHERE [Forms]![Search]![Textbox1] > 0 AND [Forms]![Search]![Textbox1] = Nlog.CoNo`

Comment: @valverij that first part is not valid sql for Access.

Comment: @gdoron that is also not valid in Access Sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use regular logic:

```
Select *
From NLog
Where ([Forms]![Search]![Textbox1] <= 0 OR [Forms]![Search]![Textbox1] = Nlog.CoNo);
```

Note:  this assumes that `[Forms]![Search]![Textbox1]` is not `NULL`.  If that is a possibility, you can handle that using explicit logic or the `NZ()` function.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense.  Will that let me repeat that logic more than once in one query or will I need subqueries?

Comment: @SarahSedaii You can use as many criteria as you like, just make sure to group sets of criteria with parenthesis.

Comment: I got the following error in access: "This express in typed incorrectly, or it is too complex to be evaluated.  For example, a numeric express may contain too many complicated elemtents.  Try simplifying the expression by assigning parts of the expression to variables." Here is the code:SELECT *
FROM NLog
Where ([Forms]![FrmSearch]![Combo13] >= 0) OR ((NLog.State)=[Forms]![FrmSearch]![Combo13])

Comment: GOT IT! instead of 0 I had to type in NULL

Comment: @SarahSedaii . . . Then you want `is null` or `is not null`, depending on the meaning you want.

Comment: you are wonderful! You anticpated the error before I could even type it

Answer (score 0):

If you read [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Rule_of_Material_Implication/Formulation_1) you can see that a material injunction (IF-THEN) can be converted to a disjunction (OR). So in your case you'll have:

```
NOT [Forms]![Search]![Textbox1] > 0 OR [Forms]![Search]![Textbox1] = Nlog.CoNo
```